# wagtail-footnotes implementation trouble

Tags: wagtail

I've tried following the readme but it renders the footnotes as their [uuid] both in admin and frontend.

blog.py

```
from wagtail_footnotes.blocks import RichTextBlockWithFootnotes
class BlogPage(Page):
    body = RichTextField(blank=True, features=["bold", "italic", "ol", "ul", "hr", "link", "document-link", "footnotes",])

    extras = StreamField([
        ("testimonial", SnippetChooserBlock(
            target_model='testimonials.Testimonial',
            template="streams/testimonial_block.html"
            )
        ),
        ("RichTextBlockWithFootnotes", RichTextBlockWithFootnotes(label=("RichText with Footnotes"),
                features=["bold", "italic", "ol", "ul", "hr", "link", "footnotes", "document-link"]
            )),
            ("large_image", blocks.ImageChooserBlock(
                template = "streams/large_image_block.html"
            )),
    ], null=True, blank=True, use_json_field=True)

content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
    FieldPanel('body'),
    FieldPanel("extras"),

    InlinePanel('footnotes', label="Footnotes")
```

I've included the template tag at the start of {% block content %} of my blog_page.html

```
{% block content %}
{% include "wagtail_footnotes/includes/footnotes.html" %}
```

and am calling the body like this:
blog_page.html

```
{% block content %}
{% include "wagtail_footnotes/includes/footnotes.html" %}
    <div class="block-richtext">
        {{ page.body|richtext }}
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

It looks like in the wagtail_footnotes/includes/footnotes.html file that this section is not getting reached and I'm not sure why:

```
{% for footnote in page.footnotes_list %}
```

If I try:

```
body RichTextBlockWithFootnotes(blank=True, features=["bold", "italic", "ol", "ul", "hr", "link", "footnotes", "document-link"])
```

I get this error:

> django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (body) specified
> for BlogPage

I've attached an image showing how the footnote is rendered in a RichTextField body with 'body' as the content and 'TEST' as the footnote.[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the RichTextField implementation is incomplete. You could use the https://github.com/torchbox/wagtail-footnotes/pull/37/files#r998749704 approach (using a custom template tag) as a workaround until I release a fix for this

Comment: Thanks I did try to do that but not sure how to load/register the richtext _footnotes tag.

Comment: I got this error:

Comment: 'richtext_footnotes' is not a registered tag library. Must be one of:
admin list admin_modify admin_urls cache debugger_tags highlighting i18n indent text
110n
log
menu tags
modeladmin_tags static syntax color table block tags tz wagtailadmin_tags wagtailcore_tags wagtailembeds_tags wagtailimages_tags wagtailsettings_tags wagtailsnippets_admin_tags wagtailuserbar wagtailusers_tags widget_tweaks widont

Answer (score 0):

I was able to implement @zerolab's workaround, the issue I had before trying to do that was I'm a Django beginner and didn't understand how to use template tags.

Creating an app richtext_footnotes with folder templatetags, an empty `__init__.py` file and a templatetags/richtext_footnotes.py file with the following code got me to the point where footnotes are at least rendering on the frontend:

```py
from django import template
import re
from wagtail.models import Page
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe


register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def richtext_footnotes(context, html):
    """
    example: {% richtext_footnotes page.body|richtext %}

    html: already processed richtext field html
    Assumes "page" in context.
    """
    FIND_FOOTNOTE_TAG = re.compile(r'<footnote id="(.*?)">.*?</footnote>')

    if not isinstance(context.get("page"), Page):
        return html

    page = context["page"]
    if not hasattr(page, "footnotes_list"):
        page.footnotes_list = []
    footnotes = {str(footnote.uuid): footnote for footnote in page.footnotes.all()}

    def replace_tag(match):
        try:
            index = process_footnote(match.group(1), page)
        except (KeyError, ValidationError):
            return ""
        else:
            return f'<a href="#footnote-{index}" id="footnote-source-{index}"><sup>[{index}]</sup></a>'

    def process_footnote(footnote_id, page):
        footnote = footnotes[footnote_id]
        if footnote not in page.footnotes_list:
            page.footnotes_list.append(footnote)
        # Add 1 to the index as footnotes are indexed starting at 1 not 0.
        return page.footnotes_list.index(footnote) + 1

    return mark_safe(FIND_FOOTNOTE_TAG.sub(replace_tag, html))
```

In the template just need to load:

```
{% richtext_footnotes %}
```

and use:

```
{% richtext_footnotes page.body %}
```

To show all footnotes at the bottom of the page.html:

```html
<ol>
     {% for footnote in page.footnotes.all %}
         <li id="footnote-{{ forloop.counter }}">
         [{{ forloop.counter }}] {{
             footnote.text|richtext }}
              <a href="#footnote-source-{{
         forloop.counter }}" aria-label="Back to content">↩</a>    
         </li>
     {% endfor %}
</ol>
```